# how to display two lines for same field but from different hosts in same visualization?

Tags: kibana-6

how to display two lines for same field but from different hosts in same visualization using kibana?

I have peakload values from two different hosts and i want them to be displayed in same visualization each line representing peakload values for each host.

suppose there is **host1** and **host2**.
then **line1** should represent peakload values for **host1** and **line2** should represent **peakload** values for **host2**.
how should i do it?
**Both the lines should be present in same visualization**

**Edit 1:**

this is the plot for graph containing peakload from single host
but if i have multiple hosts, how to plot peakload values from multiple hosts in same plot

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzCIi.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add a minimal code example to clarify your issue.

Comment: @MartinReiche currently i have only one host configured so i cannot do it practically, but in future if i have multiple hosts then how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Y-axis**

Aggregation - `Max`

Field - `MaxPeakLoad`

**X-axis**

Aggregation - `Date Histogram`

Field - `Timestamp`

Interval - `Auto`

**Split Series**

Sub Aggregation - `Terms`

Field - `beat.hostname` or some field which has your host name. You will ideally have a field like beat.hostname which has host name if you are using filebeat or metricbeat

Order By - `metric:Max` or your preference

Since we are aggregating by hostname field, if you are sending 10 hosts's data to your cluster ALL of them should display in this visualization.